# What kind of database to use?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

i am going to create my first application .it is an application about movies ,well the point is: my application is going to have 2 db tables where it contains varchars and fotos (pictures).but i am not sure which database to use (mysql??,sqlite??),
have i to buy a server ?.

another question ,i want do to a version for Android ,have i to use the same database or create 2 databases one for pc and the other one for Android ?

i Don't know so much about database and distribution ,all i know is how to connect to a database in my own pc .

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks !

Comment: I believe android only supports sqlite databases. But you can store files on the device itself in directories. Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

on Android you have to use sqlite. The difference between the both is not very big. DONT BUY A SERVER.

What's your idea? One database for both clients? A database on each device?

Comment: well,i want a database where every user can connect to the tables (users ,movies).

Comment: Program your server with java or anything else. Search for restlet and jdbc.